# Create a service and app that use the same DB in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service

I would like to know if the following is possible. I would like to create an Application that creates a database in SQLite, I then want to create a service that is stand alone, in other words, the service is not create by the Application, it is started on its own. The service must the be able to access the database created by the Application.

Is what I am trying to do possible with an SQLite database? I read about content providers but have never used them. The second thing I would like to know is can I create a service like I intent to?

Thanks,
Wihan

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a service without a app. Your app may not have any UI, but you need a app.
To receive a broadcast you app need be "[active](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/)", see more here.
I don't think you can share database(SQLite database) between different apps. This answer can help you, but there is other types of [data storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) that may help you.